# How to restart adb from root to user mode?

Tags: android, adb, root

Basic question on ADB.

`adb root` restarts adb as root. But what i want is to restart it back to user after some time.

I tried the following :

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

doesnt work..

`ps -A` -> noted the process number of adb and killed it.. even this did not work. Finally i am restarting my device. Is there any way i can come back from root adb to general adb?

Thank you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you used `adb root`, you would have got the following message:

```
C:\>adb root
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
restarting adbd as root
```

To get out of the root mode, you can use:

```
C:\>adb unroot
restarting adbd as non root
```

Comment: this solution did not work for me. unknown option `unroot`. Alex P's solution worked.

Answer (score 32):

`adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` only control the `adb` daemon on the PC side. You need to restart `adbd` daemon on the device itself after reverting the `service.adb.root` property change done by `adb root`:

```
~$ adb shell id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)

~$ adb root
restarting adbd as root

~$ adb shell id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)

~$ adb shell 'setprop service.adb.root 0; setprop ctl.restart adbd'

~$ adb shell id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)
```

Comment: hi. I tried it. the deice is still in root mode after performing the steps.

Comment: you either doing it wrong or your device is non stock android... see my update

Answer (score 11):

Try this to make sure you get your shell back:

enter adb shell (root). Then type below comamnd.

```
stop adbd && setprop service.adb.root 0 && start adbd &
```

This command will `stop adbd`, then `setprop service.adb.root 0` if `adbd` has been successfully `stop`ped, and finally re`start adbd` should the `.root` property have successfully been set to 0. And all this will be done in the background thanks to the last `&`.

Comment: This one works perfect :) But user might get confused where to type these.. So I wrote a noob answer

Comment: Tried this and my device (on Lollipop 5.1) went just blank.... Don't know what happened, just removed battery and put it back & switched it ON :/

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a little more explanation to @user837048's answer. on my OSX Yosemite and Galaxy S3 which is rooted and using firmware `CyanogenMod 11` and `KitKat` I have done the below proceedings to `Enable` and `Disable` root prompt.

Please make ensure below

- On your system

  - Make sure you have installed `Android SDK` and you have set paths to binary files. type `which adb` on your shell. It must give you somewhat result.

    `$ which adb
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools/adb`
- On your Mobile

  - Settings > Developer Options> Android Debugging = `ON`
  - Settings > Developer Options> Root Access = `Apps and ADB`

*If you don't see `Developer Options` in your settings, Goto Settings > About Phone. Scroll down to `Build number` and tap there 7 times. I know its crazy. But believe me it works :D*

Connect your phone via USB Cable. 
type on your `computer's` terminal

```
$ adb shell
```

you will see a prompt similiar, **If any prompt has been shown on your mobile, to trust the connection, tap 'Always Trust' and 'OK'**

```
shell@m0:/ $
```

now type

```
shell@m0:/ $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

See you are `not root`

Now exit from shell, which will fall back to `computer's prompt`

```
shell@m0:/ $ exit
```

Now activate root

```
$adb shell
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
root@m0:/ #
```

**Wow.. you are root**

```
root@m0:/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

*I tried many solutions to go back to `normal non root prompt`. But didn't worked except @user837048's solution.*

```
root@m0:/ # stop adbd && setprop service.adb.root 0 && start adbd &
[1] 32137
root@m0:/ #
$
```

This might exit you from `Adb prompt` to normal prompt. Now connect again.

```
$ adb shell
shell@m0:/ $
```

**Well.. You are Non root**

Answer (score 0):

For quick steps just check **summary**. If interested to know details, go on to read below.

adb is a daemon. Doing `ps adb` we can see its process.

```
shell@grouper:/ $ ps adb
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC        NAME
shell     133   1     4636   212   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
```

I just checked what additional property variables it is using when adb is running as root and user.

**adb user mode :**

```
shell@grouper:/ $ getprop | grep adb                                         
[init.svc.adbd]: [running]
[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[ro.adb.secure]: [1]
[sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[sys.usb.state]: [mtp,adb]
```

**adb root mode :**

```
shell@grouper:/ # getprop | grep adb                                         
[init.svc.adbd]: [running]
[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[ro.adb.secure]: [1]
[service.adb.root]: [1]
[sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[sys.usb.state]: [mtp,adb]
```

We can see that `service.adb.root` is a new prop variable that came up when we did adb root.

So, to change back adb to user from root, I went ahead and made this 0

```
setprop service.adb.root 0
```

But this did not change anything.

Then I went ahead and killed the process (with an intention to restart the process). The `pid` of `adbd` process in my device is `133`

```
kill -9 133
```

I exited from shell automatically after I had killed the process.

I did `adb shell` again it was in user mode.

**SUMMARY :**

So, we have 3 very simple steps.

1. Enter adb shell as a root.
2. setprop service.adb.root 0
3. kill -9 `(pid of adbd)`

After these steps just re-enter the shell with `adb shell` and you are back on your device as a user.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very common issue.

One solution is to **kill adb server** and **restart** it through command prompt. Sometimes this may not help out.

Just go to Window Task Manager to kill adb process and restart Eclipse.

Will work perfect :)

Comment: Then try to kill adb server through command prompt. It may work from your side.

Comment: Goto your **platform-tools** folder in sdk. Example: May be **Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools** and press **ctrl+shift and right click the mouse** to "Open Command window here". Then enter two commands **adb kill-server** and **adb start-server** keeping your IDE running.

Answer (score -1):

i've been with this issue using elementary OS loki. For like one day and i solved it restarting the adb using this command:

```
./adb kill-server
```

and

```
./adb start-server
```

*You need to be in the Sdk folder >Platform Tools*

Now, restart your phone this will restart all the process in your phone.

And that's how i fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

if you cannot access data folder on Android Device Monitor

**cmd**

```
C:\Users\bscis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
(Where you located sdk folder)

C:\Users\bscis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
generic_x86:/ $

C:\Users\bscis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server
C:\Users\bscis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

C:\Users\bscis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb root

C:\Users\bscis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>
```

working fine.....