# How to restart adbd through computer terminal?

Tags: android, adb

I use this command but I really cannot understand why it is working. I'm looking for a more clean way to restart adbd.

The command that I use and it actually works:

```
adb shell "( (su -c stop adbd &) && (su -c start adbd &) ) &"
```

I'm **just** looking for the best way to do this.

Comment: Hi, look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/15336215/5241603

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setprop ctl.restart adbd` does that. It does require `root` so

```
adb shell su 0 setprop ctl.restart adbd
```

Comment: Also This one is as long as the one asker is already using :/

Comment: I think this is not a shortcut and clean answer!